# Navigation bar doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm new to the complete web design thing and I'm using github to host this little project of mine, it's not **the best**.

This is what I'm having a problem with.
My navigation bar isn't working and I'm not sure why. I've figured out it works when I remove my index.css and leave the navbar.css in.

This is my index.css.

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("/images/background.jpg") center center no-repeat;
}
.responsive-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.img-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e6e6e6 !important;
}
```

And this is my navbar.css

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

And finally this is my index.html

```
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <title>&lrm;</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/navbar.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="text">
    <li><a class="active" href="/pwgen">Password Generator</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://thejaffaking.imgur.com">Imgur</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="responsive-container">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <a href="https://www.overbuff.com/players/pc/TheKingJaffa-2542">
        <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What I'm asking for is a little help on why it's not working properly. I'm guessing it's something in my index.css but I'm not sure what it is.

Sorry if this is fairly obvious and I'm not thinking things through

Comment: it is because .img-container - that div covers all over the page (absolute and left, right, top, bottom are zero), so your anchors are not triggered by hover. What do you want to do with the logo png? Background? or logo at top left? Anyways, you know why, but you need to decide what to do with logo, so it can be arranged how you need.

Comment: @smozgur my site is thekingjaffa.github.io if that makes it apparent

Comment: yes, @bulldozer answer will work great. But it is good to know why it happens - especially for a new subject.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the help everyone. It's much appreciated

Comment: Remember that z-index work only with: position: absolute / fixed / relative. Not with out it. Well, and small TIP. Add to img-container z-index:1 and to your all content use z-index:10 and you'll have no problem.

Comment: Of course! Glad you got it solved. Have fun with HTML. Just as a recommendation if you are at the beginning - start working with CSS frameworks like Bootstrap as soon as you can after familiarizing with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your img-container is styled to overlay content. Use `z-index` to fix navigation.

Change this in CSS:

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}
```

to this:

```
ul {
position: relative;
z-index:1; 
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. And thanks for editing your comment so I knew what it was that you did. Thanks again dude